# Ajax autocomplete extender not working in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I read many posts regarding the issue, but couldnt locate my mistake. Can anybody please help

Ajax autocomplete extender is not working

aspx.cs file

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]

```
public static List<string> getMemberInfo1(string prefixText)
{
    List<string> firstName = new List<string>();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = admObj.getMemberInfo(prefixText);

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        firstName.Add(table.Rows[i][2].ToString() + " - " + table.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " " + table.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }



    return firstName;
}
```

aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ReferralIdTextBox" runat="server" Width="200px"
AutoCompleteType="DisplayName" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ReferralIdTextBox_AutoCompleteExtender" 
    runat="server"  Enabled="True" 
    TargetControlID="ReferralIdTextBox" 
    ServiceMethod="getMemberInfo1">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

If I copy paste the same code in a new file, it works fine there.
Has is got to anything with the rest of the functions on page?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: does it returning proper data from web service?

Comment: @ashuthinks .... I m not getting the list when I type something in my text box

Comment: @ashuthinks If I copy paste the same code in a new file, it works fine there. Has is got to anything with the rest of the functions on page?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two or three things missing. You have not mentioned service path in your code. Another thing is you need to add script manager for this.

So, Please go through following link and put missing things.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit

Comment: did you put service path of your web service?

Comment: <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" 
        EnablePageMethods="True">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: Service path? ... not sure what that does .... because I have written the same code for another file without mentioning the service path and it works fine there

Comment: Have you also tried minimum prefix length and another attributes? like this link -http://allwrong.wordpress.com/2007/03/13/ms-ajax-autocomplete-extender-using-a-page-method/ . Also is it calling your page method on server side code?

Comment: I have tried minimum prefix length and other attributes as well

<asp:TextBox ID="ReferralIdTextBox" runat="server" Width="200px"
    AutoCompleteType="DisplayName" AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>



    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ReferralIdTextBox_AutoCompleteExtender" 
        runat="server" CompletionSetCount="1" ServiceMethod="getMemberInfo1" 
        TargetControlID="ReferralIdTextBox" UseContextKey="True" 
        MinimumPrefixLength="1" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="True" 
        CompletionInterval="1">
    
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

Comment: Looks like it is not calling the ServiceMethod

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled page methods in your script manager and then only add this attribute only [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

Comment: <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"> </asp:ToolkitScriptManager> ...... done

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
       </asp:ScriptManager> try this

Comment: If I copy paste the same code in a new file, it works fine there. Has is got to anything with the rest of the functions on page?

Comment: don't know can not say without seeing all your code.